# circular_reference_handler is not invoked on Symfony3.4

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I am using serializer on symfony3.4.

My code is like this below.

```
    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($place, 'json',[
        'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
            return $object->getId();
        }
    ]);
    return new JsonResponse($place);
```

However it returns the error like this,

```
A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\PlaceCat" (configured limit: 1)
```

it looks `circular_reference_handler` callback is not invoked.

How can I enabled this callback ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony 3.4 the circular reference handler was set by **a method** `Normalizer::setCircularReferenceHandler(callable)` instead of a serialization-context option.

You need to use the following for Symfony 3.4:

```
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getName();
});

$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
```

> **Deprecated since version 4.2**: The `setCircularReferenceHandler()` method is deprecated 
>   since Symfony 4.2. Use the `circular_reference_handler` key of the context instead.